# versioning api using url from WebApiConfig

Tags: api, api-versioning

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Version1",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional , controllers = "studentV1" }
            );
```

my question is, if i need this code for a lot of controllers for example

```
controllers = "emplyeeV1" , controllers ="carV1" , controllers ="CursV1"
```

do i have to copy bast this code for each controller i have in the api ?!!

is there any way like this for exmaple.

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Version1",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional , controllers = "studentV1" , controllers = "emplyeeV1" , controllers ="carV1" , controllers ="CursV1" }
            );
```

i know its wrong , but how can i do the right solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you evaluated [ASP.NET API Versioning](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning)? It can support the type of routing you want to do out-of-the-box using a single route template. You can review all the details about versioning by URL segment on the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Versioning-via-the-URL-Path). There are also several Web API [sample projects](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/webapi) that demonstrate various setups and styles. I hope that helps.